# git-svn died of signal 10 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, svn, git, git-svn

I have git and git-svn installed via [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/). I try to do the following:

```
$ git svn init http://myserver/myrepo
Initialized empty Git repository in checkout/.git/
$ git svn fetch
error: git-svn died of signal 10
```

Why is git-svn failing? How can I fix this? I have the repo already checked out via vanilla SVN, so there shouldn't be any access or permissions issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not be the only issue but to fetch the svn data you need to be in a git controlled directory. So `cd checkout` before the fetch.

Comment: Ahh, Mark, that's most likely it. I can't believe I didn't think of that!